# Get post data with unknown number of variables in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an entity with a variable set of attributes named `ExtendedProperty`, these have a key and a value.

In my html razor view, I have this:

```
@if (properties.Count > 0)
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Extended Properties</legend>
            <table>
            @foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Property-@prop.Name">@prop.Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Property-@prop.Name" 
                               value="@prop.Value"/>
                    </td>
               </tr>
            }
            </table>
        </fieldset>
}
```

How can I access this data on my controller once the user fills it in? Is there a way to do this so that I can use the model  bindings instead of manual html?

EDIT = Please note that I'm still using a model, and there are other things in the form that do use things like `@Html.EditFor(m => m.prop)`. But I couldn't find a way to integrate these variable properties in.

Thanks.

Comment: If you name the inputs Properties[0]....Properties[n], the model binder will convert this to an IEnumerable on the model named Properties

Comment: How can I integrate this with my model class?

Comment: @elite5472 Please, take a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450772/asp-net-mvc4-dynamic-form-generation/17451048#17451048. I believe that it's the same problem.

Comment: @AndreCalil Thanks, but there is an issue that I also have. I have other fields too which are static.

Comment: @elite5472 I don't understand what you mean by *static fields*. Could you provide more details about your model? Also, note that you can use the notation `Property[n].Name` and `Property[n].Value`

Comment: My model has a set number of properties, and a collection of "ExtendedProperty" objects as well. The later are variable in number while the other ones are standard C# properties.

Comment: @elite5472 Please, review the answer I've posted here. Any feedback will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have the following `Model` (*ViewModel*, I prefer):

```
public class ExtendedProperties
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }

}

public class MyModel
{
  public ExtendedProperties[] Properties { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You can bind this model to a view using a markup like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="text" name="Name" />
  <input type="number" name="Id" />

  <input type="text" name="Properties[0].Name" />
  <input type="text" name="Properties[0].Value" />  
  ...
  <input type="text" name="Properties[n].Name" />
  <input type="text" name="Properties[n].Value" />  
}
```

Finally, your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(MyModel model)
{
  //simply retrieve model.Properties[0]
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the FormCollection object passed to the controller method?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
{
  foreach (string extendedProperty in formCollection)
  {
     if (extendedProperty.Contains("Property-"))
     {
       string extendedPropertyValue = formCollection[extendedProperty];
     }
  }

  ...
}
```

I would try traversing through the items in that collection.