# MVC Send a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got an `Index View` with a table populated with data from a List property, but when I post the form with the table, the property is null.

Here is the Model:

```
public class BillViewModel
{

    public List<Product> ListProducts { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the product view:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<input type="submit" value="Aceptar"/>


<table id="tabla">


    @foreach (var item in Model.ListProducts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
}
```

I can add or delete Products, but how can i get the product list in the controller?:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BillViewModel billViewModel)
    {


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Please, review this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450772/asp-net-mvc4-dynamic-form-generation/17451048#17451048 It's the same problem, I'm sure it will solve yours.

Comment: Yes you can get all details in your control. Mvc flow is that controller communicate with both modal and view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite easy, all you need to do is place all the item properties in the form, so something like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Aceptar"/>
<table id="tabla">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProducts.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ListProducts[i].ProductId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ListProducts[i].Price)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ListProducts[i].ProductName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I use a for instead a foreach giving an index to the list, to each property. All using a HiddenFor. And It works.

Comment: @DiegoUnanue Glad It does :) Feel free to mark it as an answer if it's what you're looking for :) Good luck. Cheers

Comment: What happens if I add a new row, for example i've got a textbox where i can add a new Product, this product isn't in the database so it hasn's id. What arquitectural aprouch can I use to send all products and insert into the database those that aren't in it. It have ProductId and ProductName, I can find those names that are not in the database. But if i can have repeated productNames?

Comment: @DiegoUnanue in your case if I'm supposed to add a new element I'd probably do an ajax post add a new element -> get back the result and add the new item along the rest on the form (following the same structure) this time however my item would have an Id. I hope this helps.

Comment: I was using foreach instead of for loop, which is why list was not submitting , changing it to for loop did it. Thanks!